# Realm select by property of property

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two `RealmModels`

```
class Shop{

    private String name;
    private Item item;

}

class Item{
    private int itemId;
    private String itemName;
}
```

I want to find the shop that has an item with `itemId = 1`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query across references (links) in Realm. So the below should work:

```
realm.where(Shop.class).equalTo("item.itemId", 1).findFirst()
```